# how can i validate email exist on two table in ci

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have two table vendor and user .show how can we validate email exist both table.

```
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|is_unique[user.email]|valid_email','call_back_mail',array('required' => 'You have not provided %s.', 'is_unique' => 'This %s already exists.'));
```

Comment: Use callback function

Answer (score 1):

```
Add this in your .php file (controller) 
$form_validation->Form_validation($emails,'Email',"require|validemail|check_unique-admin_details-users_details-email");

//and add this code in the validation.php (library)
case "check_unique":
                    $result= $this->validation_check_unique($data,$name,$key1[1],$key1[2],$key1[3]);
                    break;

//
function validation_check_unique($data="",$name,$table,$table1,$fieldname)
    {

        $sql = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select $fieldname from $table where $fieldname = '$data'"));
        if($data == $sql[0])
        {
            $sql1 = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select $fieldname from $table1 where $fieldname = '$data'"));
            if($data == $sql1[0])
            {
                array_push($this->validation_array,"<i class='fa fa-arrow-circle-right'></i> $name already exist.");
                return FALSE;
            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't undrestend if vendor and user tables are php array or  sql table ?